# Css Content is cut off

Tags: html, css, styles, css-position

My Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ymkokef5/

My Problem (the X seems cut off) - How can I position the X within the "box"?

[image]

I am using `<button class="modal-close"></button>` on my Demo Site.

I want to position an "X" (close) at the top-left.

```css
.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 28px;
  left: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  color: #888888;
}

.modal-close::after {
  content: "X";
}

.modal-close::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.025em;
  left: -0.1em;
  padding: 0
}

.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  /* establish flex container */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* make main-axis vertical */
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align items vertically, in this case */
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* align items horizontally, in this case */
  height: 100%;
  /* for demo purposes */
  width: 100%;
}

#Kurzfilm video {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

#Kurzfilm .overlay {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 80;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#Kurzfilm video,
#modal .window {
  z-index: 90;
}

#Kurzfilm {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 90;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1vw;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="Kurzfilm">
  <button class="modal-close"></button>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="flexbox">
    <video width="320" height="240">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ehm, adjust the `top` and `left` properties of the `::after`?

Comment: `X` have `absolute` position and need a relative parent and fixed width, you should wrap your image with a relative div with a certain width

Comment: @pedram A parent to an absolutely positioned child can have any kind of positioning, not just relative.

Comment: I was able to accommodate its dimensions by increasing the height of the "container" and yes (thanks Lister) adjusting top+left of the :after absolute position. https://jsfiddle.net/ymkokef5/1/

Comment: @MrLister not my word, if OP want to put `X` on img need to set certain width and of course postion relative.

Comment: @pedram There is no img.

Comment: This question so confusing, why should add `x` via `::after` when you can put that `x` directly on button! anyway, you want use `::after`? ok so why you set position absolute for `::after` there is no need to do this, just set position for button like this https://jsfiddle.net/ymkokef5/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
.modal-close::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0em;
  left: 0em;
  padding: 0
}
```

Make the top and left = 0em, this will bring it to the absolute corner

OR

```
.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow-x: visible;
  top: 28px;
  left: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  color: #888888;
}
```

Make the overflow-x as visible to uncut the X

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes

```
.modal-close::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.1em;
    left: 0.03em;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple:

Give the font-size for the class .modal-close::after

```
.modal-close::after {
content: "X";
font-size: 18px;
```

}

Move the left side

```
.modal-close::after {
position: absolute;
top: -0.025em;
left: 0.9em;
padding: 0;
```

}

I have updated in the  jsfiddle